# Proving the double summation identity: $\sum_{x=1}^a\sum_{y=1}^b xy = \left(\sum_{x=1}^a x\right)\left(\sum_{y=1}^b y\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

How can one prove the following using substitution and the knowledge of special sums?

$$\sum_{x=1}^a\sum_{y=1}^b xy = \left(\sum_{x=1}^a x\right)\left(\sum_{y=1}^b y\right)$$

I am trying to use the fact that the sum of a constant variable is equal to $x(x + 1)/2$, but since the two variables are different, I am struggling to unite them. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: for every $a$ that is independent of $k$,$$\sum_kaf(k)=a\sum_kf(k)$$

Comment: Also, in the future, please take a look here to format your math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.  You need at least 10 reputation to post images.